# VBA GF(256) log table

Tags: vba, ms-access, qr-code, galois-field, finite-field

I'm working on a function to generate QR codes in vba. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/introduction/). I am now working on generating the error correction words in [this step](http://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/part-2-error-correction/). This requires GF(256) log/antilog tables, [seen here](http://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/log-antilog-table/). I really don't want to have to type in the whole table. Does anyone know the function used to generate these tables so I can just store them in arrays? The tutorial had a link to how the tables were generated but it was broken.

I should have mentioned it earlier, but this will be run in access, so pasting into excel won't work very well. But as I'm writing this I'm realizing I could use an access table. Though I would prefer to just do it all in code.

Comment: Are you using Excel to run the VBA?

Comment: @A.Webb I think that is the way to go. Sometimes the most obvious answers are the last ones you think of. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Const GF = 256 '// define the Size & Prime Polynomial of this Galois field
Const PP = 285
Dim logg(GF)  'establish global Log and Antilog arrays
Dim alogg(GF)


'fill the logg() and alogg() arrays with appropriate integer values

logg(0) = 1
alogg(0) = 1

For i = 1 To 255
  alogg(i) = alogg(i - 1) * 2
  If alogg(i) >= GF Then alogg(i) = alogg(i) Xor PP
  logg(alogg(i)) = i
Next i
```